# Deleting a question and leaving a note to users who may have been writing an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes one may post a question to a particular SE site, and then they may realize (possibly with help of a commenter) that this question better fits other SE site, so the poster deletes their question and posts it to the other site.

While this is happening, other users may have been writing an answer, and after pressing **[answer]** button, they get *question was deleted by poster* message, though their answer may have been useful to the poster. Usually people don't go looking where the poster may have moved his question and the effort is wasted, but in some cases (advances users) they do and they are good people for doing that :)

I think this should be solved by the site itself. For example provide a tip that suggests to look at similar questions recently posted by the user, including other SE sites.

One other way is to let the user who deletes their question mark a checkbox "*I intend to post this deleted question on another SE site*", preferrably with an option to later link to it, so users who may have already typed their answers post them there.

Comment: Why would you even start writing an answer to a question that doesn't belong to the right SE site? There's a `close` button you could use instead to select the appropriate site where the question should be migrated.

Comment: Some people just answer questions, caring about the asker's problem more than the site's rules. I for one don't have a problem with that. Moderator can move both the question and answer to the appropriate SE site later.

Comment: Well, then you should live with the fact that you might have wasted your efforts because before putting efforts into something you should ask yourself whether this something is legit (in terms of SE, whether it belongs to the right SE site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this is that the considerate asker should NOT delete the question. Instead, add a comment saying you've realized it belongs on another site, then FLAG it for migration. This

- is less work than asking it again on the other site
- doesn't run the risk of a question ban due to deleted questions
- brings the existing answers over, which is nicer to your answerers

Win-Win-Win.