# For quality blocks / warnings, system seems to penalize migrated answered questions the same as deleted ones

Tags: support, post-ban, rate-limiting, question-quality

As far as I know, [question blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271543/839601) / [quality warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773) system tends to rather heavily [penalize deleted *answered* questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773):

> <sup>The folks we're concerned about are the ones who ask a question, and then delete it *as soon as they get an answer* - for whatever reasons, there are folks (and used to be more of them...) who intentionally thwart the very purpose of the site - allowing answers to go on and benefit others. It's overtly abusive behavior, and doing that repeatedly is a really good way for a new user to get blocked...</sup>

When discussing one recent [case of quality warning](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6909/31260) it turned out that system doesn't seem to differentiate whether answer(s) were plainly deleted along with the question or this happened as a result of migration.

I would like to better understand the reasoning behind treating these cases the same. I expect this to help me discuss blocks / warnings related to migrated questions.

Comment: it seems that penalizing for answers deleted at migration is not intended: "Irrelevant unless mod-deleted; counts as a closed question." –  [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287902/how-much-of-an-effect-do-deleted-questions-have-on-bans/287903?noredirect=1#comment164814_287903 "quote source")