# "not well received" warning displayed improperly

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

Whilst trying to improve my involvement in the network, I was about to ask a new question, and got this message saying I have some questions "not well received" and I might be blocked from asking!

I think something is not accurate about this flagging system algorithm.
I'll explain.

1. While reviewing my questions, I found some *are* bad questions, and I wanted to remove them was noted I might be blocked from asking more questions, if I do so.
   In overall my account's credibility seems well, so that warning seemed a bit off to me.
2. I did ask another question, while having that warning there, and after that I do not see that warning again!
3. a few days ago I was downvoted on commenting an answer irrelevant [which it was]
4. only now [after a day of making this question] did Stack Exchange merge all of my network's accounts. My account now appears much better.

I'm thinking maybe the warning system calculated my account is up for a question ban unfairly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow)

Comment: @gnat not a dupe anymore.

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably not a dupe anymore indeed. Warning may be too eager in some cases ([related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240660/165773)). I think I saw SE team folks admitting that; if memory serves they explained that less sensitive heuristics turned out incapable to timely warn some folks who were sliding into ban really fast so they had to compromise to trade timely help for relatively high rate of false alerts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally get this warning quite a few questions before you actually get the block.

Reasons you *might* get this message:

- You're deleting a lot of your posts
- A moderator(s) is deleting some of your posts
- A few of your recent questions have been closed
- You've got a lot of downvotes on your recent questions

The things you can do to improve:

- Get any closed questions reopened by improving them
- Answer well to another question
- Ask good, high-quality questions, *after researching*, and *showing your research*

I realize that not all these bullet points apply to you, but I'm just putting it out there.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're on the verge of getting a question ban. [This post explains question bans in great detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), but the key point is that you've had too many questions which got downvoted, closed, or deleted (whether or not you delete a question yourself doesn't affect this).

The best thing you can do is **improve your poorly-received questions** as much as possible so that they might get upvoted, reopened or undeleted.

If you're unsure why a specific question got poorly received or how to improve it, you can ask for clarification on the site's meta or the associated chat room.

Comment: what if today they seem like bad questions? should i deleted them?
+ How is a question poorly received if it has an answer, quite a few views, and no down votes?

Comment: If a question has no down/close/delete votes, then it won't contribute to a question ban. I'm not a moderator, so I don't know exactly which questions are causing the problem for you.