# Should I delete my own questions with answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, rate-limiting

I don't know much about this,

But I've some of the questions on which some user has answered (not helpful answer) also but I want to delete those questions, but whenever I go to delete that question. It is prompting with

[image: screen shot of deletion warning]

What does it mean? Can someone tell me what would be the action taken by Stack Exchange if I delete more questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting your answered question is considered abusive and question block algorithm counts it heavily against you:

> The folks we're concerned about are the ones who ask a question, and then delete it *as soon as they get an answer* - for whatever reasons, there are folks (and used to be more of them...) who intentionally thwart the very purpose of the site - allowing answers to go on and benefit others. It's overtly abusive behavior, and **doing that repeatedly is a really good way for a new user to get blocked**.

<sub>(quote source: [Require a minimum rep to delete your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773); **bold font** in quote is mine)</sub>

See also:

- [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)
- [Do you get question bans by deleting your own posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/839601)

Answer (score 1):

As it was stated in the cited link

> Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?

you need not worry about that warning, even if you are a new member. I have deleted lots of questions without any problem. You can delete a question if it has no answer, if it has one answer with no upvotes, and even if there are two answers withe negative scores. In other cases you are asked to flag your own question and ask for deletion.

The ban is enforced for new users with low rep when they have some question closed and/or with negative rating. Even then it is not a real ban, and in most sites (they can have different procedures) you are just restricted to one question per week.

It is not your case, anyway, since you received an association bonus in all sites